# What is the best way to print all the dates contained on some objects dates ranges inside an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, functional-programming, momentjs

If I have an array of objects like this:

```
{
    "workPeriods": [
        {
            "user_id": "9345bf",
            "startDate": "2018-02-05T05:00:00.000Z",
            "endDate": "2018-02-09T05:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "user_id": "80c3a9",
            "startDate": "2018-02-12T05:00:00.000Z",
            "endDate": "2018-02-16T05:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "user_id": "35jh87",
            "startDate": "2018-02-19T05:00:00.000Z",
            "endDate": "2018-02-23T05:00:00.000Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

What is the *best way* to print all the dates contained on each one of the objects dates range?
This need to be done using Moment jS

The result should be something like this:

```
'Work days: 02/05, 02/06, 02/07, 02/08, 02/09,   02/12, 02/13, 02/14, 02/15, 02/16,   02/19, 02/20, 02/21, 02/22, 02/23'
```

Any suggestion?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly do you mean by the "*best*" way to solve your problem, because you have not specified the criteria to evaluate the solution against. Seeing the [functional-programming](/questions/tagged/functional-programming) among other tag makes me write some code which I think is relevant.

In the code below (which you can [test out here](https://jsbin.com/bozuro/edit?html,js,console,output)):

- First `map()` translates each work period into a set of days in such period. This will result in "array of arrays".
- `reduce()` flattens the arrays into a single one.
- The `map()` is then formatting each moment.js `Moment` object into its string representaion.
- Finally, `join(' ')` transforms it in into a single string where all the dates are space separated.

---

If you write **in ES6 or TypeScript**:

```
const sourceObject = {
  "workPeriods": [
    {"user_id":"9345bf", "startDate":"2018-02-05T05:00:00.000Z", "endDate":"2018-02-09T05:00:00.000Z"},
    {"user_id":"80c3a9", "startDate":"2018-02-12T05:00:00.000Z", "endDate":"2018-02-16T05:00:00.000Z"},
    {"user_id":"35jh87", "startDate":"2018-02-19T05:00:00.000Z", "endDate":"2018-02-23T05:00:00.000Z"}
  ]
};

const userFriendlyWorkPeriodsDayList = sourceObject
  .workPeriods
  .map(workPeriod => {
    const allDaysInRange = [];
    const currentDate = moment(workPeriod.startDate);
    const endDate = moment(workPeriod.endDate);

    while (currentDate.isBefore(endDate)) {
      allDaysInRange.push(currentDate.clone());
      currentDate.add(1, 'days');
    }

    return allDaysInRange;
  })
  .reduce((accumulator, current) => (accumulator.push(...current), accumulator), [])
  .map(date => date.format('MM/DD'))
  .join(' ');

const result = `Work days: ${userFriendlyWorkPeriodsDayList}`;
```

---

Same code rewritten **in older versions of JavaScript** require usage of `function` keyword instead of `=>`. They may also lack spread operator support (`.push(...arrayOfValuesBeingPushed)`).

```
const sourceObject = {
  "workPeriods": [
    {"user_id":"9345bf", "startDate":"2018-02-05T05:00:00.000Z", "endDate":"2018-02-09T05:00:00.000Z"},
    {"user_id":"80c3a9", "startDate":"2018-02-12T05:00:00.000Z", "endDate":"2018-02-16T05:00:00.000Z"},
    {"user_id":"35jh87", "startDate":"2018-02-19T05:00:00.000Z", "endDate":"2018-02-23T05:00:00.000Z"}
  ]
};

const userFriendlyWorkPeriodsDayList = sourceObject
  .workPeriods
  .map(function (workPeriod) {
    const allDaysInRange = [];
    const currentDate = moment(workPeriod.startDate);
    const endDate = moment(workPeriod.endDate);

    while (currentDate.isBefore(endDate)) {
      allDaysInRange.push(currentDate.clone());
      currentDate.add(1, 'days');
    }

    return allDaysInRange;
  })
  .reduce(function (accumulator, current) { accumulator.push(...current); return accumulator; }, [])
  .map(function (date) { return date.format('MM/DD'); })
  .join(' ');

const result = `Work days: ${userFriendlyWorkPeriodsDayList}`;

console.log(result)
```

---

Comment: Thanks for your answer Igor!
And you're right I was talking about functional-programming!

I have an additional question in your answer...
Even that I've studied ES6 in the past, just recently I had to start using it. So I'm getting a "Unexpected use of comma operator  no-sequences" lint error on the reduce line.

I fixed the problem by separating the push line and returning the accumulator in a different line... But can you please explain to me the syntax on `(accumulator.push(...current), accumulator)` to be the same  result a: ` accumulator.push(...current); return accumulator;`

Comment: @LeonardoUribe glad to help. `(a; b; c; ...; x; z)` will execute all the expressions `a`, `b`, `c`, ..., `x` in that precise order, and "return" the value of the last expression, which is `z`. You can read this section of MDN doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator#Processing_and_then_returning (I recommend to read the entire doc, though). Please consider accepting, up voting my answer if you find it helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce` to get the days between the `startDate` and `endDate` for each object in an array. Then get the distinct dates using `Set` and `Array#from` and wrap it in an object.

```js
var data = {"workPeriods":[ {"user_id":"9345bf", "startDate":"2018-02-05T05:00:00.000Z", "endDate":"2018-02-09T05:00:00.000Z"}, {"user_id":"80c3a9", "startDate":"2018-02-12T05:00:00.000Z", "endDate":"2018-02-16T05:00:00.000Z"}, {"user_id":"35jh87", "startDate":"2018-02-19T05:00:00.000Z",
"endDate":"2018-02-23T05:00:00.000Z"} ]};

var result = data.workPeriods.reduce((r, {startDate, endDate}) => {
  var dates = [], startDate = moment(startDate), endDate = moment(endDate);
  while (startDate.isSameOrBefore(endDate)) {
      dates.push(startDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY').substring(0,5));
      startDate.add(1, 'days');
  }
 return r.concat(dates);
},[]);

var distinctDates = {'work days': Array.from(new Set(result))};

console.log(distinctDates);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you asked for a [functional-programming](/questions/tagged/functional-programming) solution, I used a recurive function called `getWorkingdays` to get all days between a start and an end day. After this you can use `map` to iterate over the `data.workingdays` to execute `getWorkingdays` on it.

## Example

```js
const data = {
  "workPeriods": [{
    "user_id": "9345bf",
    "startDate": "2018-02-05T05:00:00.000Z",
    "endDate": "2018-02-09T05:00:00.000Z"
  }, {
    "user_id": "80c3a9",
    "startDate": "2018-02-12T05:00:00.000Z",
    "endDate": "2018-02-16T05:00:00.000Z"
  }, {
    "user_id": "35jh87",
    "startDate": "2018-02-19T05:00:00.000Z",
    "endDate": "2018-02-23T05:00:00.000Z"
  }]
}

const flatMap = (arr, fn) => 
  [].concat.apply([], arr).map(fn)

const addDays = (day, numberOfDays) =>
  moment(day).add(numberOfDays, 'days')

const format_MM_DD = date =>
  moment(date).format('MM/DD')

const getWorkingdays = (start, end, workingdays = []) =>
  moment(start).isSameOrBefore(end) 
    ? getWorkingdays(addDays(start, 1), end, workingdays.concat(start)) 
    : workingdays

const workingdays = data.workPeriods.map(({startDate, endDate}) => 
  getWorkingdays(startDate, endDate)
)
  
const formattedWorkingdays = flatMap(workingdays, format_MM_DD)

console.log('Work days:', formattedWorkingdays.join(', '))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

## A more Functional Example

This solution uses [`currying`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying) and [function composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition_(computer_science)) (`pipe`). It has some boilerplate functions witch are obsolete if you are using a libary like ramda.

```
pipe(reduceWorkingdays, flatMap(format_MM_DD), join(', '))(data.workPeriods)
```

```js
const data = {
  "workPeriods": [{
    "user_id": "9345bf",
    "startDate": "2018-02-05T05:00:00.000Z",
    "endDate": "2018-02-09T05:00:00.000Z"
  }, {
    "user_id": "80c3a9",
    "startDate": "2018-02-12T05:00:00.000Z",
    "endDate": "2018-02-16T05:00:00.000Z"
  }, {
    "user_id": "35jh87",
    "startDate": "2018-02-19T05:00:00.000Z",
    "endDate": "2018-02-23T05:00:00.000Z"
  }]
}

// boilerplate code 
const pipe = (...fns) => x => fns.reduce((v, f) => f(v), x)

const map = fn => arr =>
  arr.map(fn)
  
const flatMap = fn => arr =>
  map(fn)([].concat.apply([], arr))

const reduce = fn => startValue => arr => 
  arr.reduce(fn, startValue)
  
const join = joiner => arr =>
  arr.join(joiner)

// logic
const isSameOrBefore = (compareDate, date) =>
  moment(compareDate).isSameOrBefore(date)

const addDays = (day, numberOfDays) =>
  moment(day).add(numberOfDays, 'days')

const format_MM_DD = date =>
  moment(date).format('MM/DD')

const getWorkingdays = (start, end, workingdays = []) =>
  isSameOrBefore(start, end) 
    ? getWorkingdays(addDays(start, 1), end, workingdays.concat(start)) 
    : workingdays

const reduceWorkingdays = flatMap(
  ({startDate, endDate}) => getWorkingdays(startDate, endDate)
)

console.log(
  'work days:', 
  pipe(reduceWorkingdays, flatMap(format_MM_DD), join(', '))(data.workPeriods)
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you could iterate the workperiods object key. [JSbin](https://jsbin.com/muqexor/edit?html,js,console,output)

```
let data =  {"workPeriods":[

{"user_id":"9345bf", "startDate":"2018-02-05T05:00:00.000Z", "endDate":"2018-02-09T05:00:00.000Z"},

{"user_id":"80c3a9", "startDate":"2018-02-12T05:00:00.000Z", "endDate":"2018-02-16T05:00:00.000Z"},

{"user_id":"35jh87", "startDate":"2018-02-19T05:00:00.000Z", "endDate":"2018-02-23T05:00:00.000Z"}

]}
let result = ['Work days']

data.workPeriods.forEach((time) =>{
  result.push(moment(time.startDate).format('MM/DD'))
})

console.log(result)
```